# Converting any fun to a suspended fun with high lamba expression

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming

I'm looking for a way to send Any function as a parameter and get back a suspended function
this is one example of the possible function and how I am solving this: 
Possible function

```
fun getSomething(): List<SomethingObject>
```

Incorrect approachment

```
suspend fun AnyClass.awaitAll(): List<SomethingObject> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { getSomething() }
```

But what I really want is something like this:

```
suspend fun <T : Any?> safeQuery(query: () -> Unit): () -> Unit {
     return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { query }
}
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with coroutines, but one mistake I see is that you are not calling the function you are passing as parameter. It should be `query()` instead of `query`.

Comment: I want to pass a Function to another functions and returns me the same function suspended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo...something like:

```
suspend fun <T : Any?> safeQuery(query: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
     return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { query }
}
```

or

```
suspend fun <T : Any?> safeQuery(query: () -> T): T {
     return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { query }
}
```

Does that answer your question?